# Hosting domain emails on Windows and Wordpress on Linux

Tags: wordpress, dns, web-hosting, windows-hosting

I am looking for some help here. I have configured my domain emails on Windows hosting and it is working fine. Next I want to deploy a Wordpress application on Linux hosting under the same domain.

It is possible to have the emails in Windows hosting and have the actual web application in Linux hosting?

I already have configured the dns of both hostings in my domain account. The emails are working fine but when I try to access to my domain name, it doesn't show up the Wordpress app (it shows up the default "Under construction" page of my Windows hosting)

Anyone can give me some advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your domain provider?

Comment: Arvixe for both Windows and Linux hosting (different accounts)

Comment: This is the howto from your provider http://blog.arvixe.com/making-dns-zone-changes-in-cpanel/ . Not too clearly. You can open ticket to Arvixe customer support if you not sure what you should do.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just point your DNS MX record of your domain to the Windows server (you seem to have this figured out already) and point the DNS A resource record to the IP address of your Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are edit the A record to your linux server. A/@/www should pointed to your linux server IP Address. And keep the MX to your Windows server.

For example, this is how to configure it on Godaddy https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-DNS-records-at-GoDaddy-for-Office-365-f40a9185-b6d5-4a80-bb31-aa3bb0cab48a